# WCF - Transport Security Mode: which user accesses the database?

Tags: c#, security, wcf

In WCF, `Net.TCP`, a client calling a service with `Transport` security and `client credentials="Windows"` (basically the following scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-windows-authentication), if the service then accesses a database and the connection string is using `Integrated Security`, which user is accessing the database? Is it the user running the *client* or the user running the *service*, for ex. a service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP:

> if the service then accesses a database and the connection string is using Integrated Security, which user is accessing the database?

The DB connection will be in the context of the WCF service.  To open the DB on their behalf you may need to *impersonate* them.

That linked example is only describing the authentication used to call the service

### See also

- [WindowsImpersonationContext Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Impersonating and Reverting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/impersonating-and-reverting)

Comment: "Impersonate them" means the service will try to open the DB as if it was the user, correct? Without impersonation it is the service account opening the connection, right?

Comment: Last clarification: this is also valid in the case service is a Windows service (not hosted on IIS) right?

Comment: @evilmandarine that's right.  Even a console app hosting a WCF service :)